# Confusion on the idea on differential dy in DQ by Tenenbaum and Pollard

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, book-recommendation

[image]

[image]

In example 6.26, the author maintains $(d\hat{x})(x,\Delta x)$ for $\Delta x$ although the function $y$ is not defined to be $\hat{x}$. Could someone explain why?

Comment: At this point, $(dy)(x,Δx)=2x\, Δx$ and the author replaces $Δx$ with $(d\hat x)$. This whole seems to be a motivation for slightly unusual notation, perhaps in an attempt to make Newton and Leibniz notation compatible with a higher meaning, and introduce infinitesimals in the direction of differential forms. You would have to check if this notation finds long-lasting application in the book. // The notation is not that unusual, in multivariate analysis a common notation for directional derivatives is $\partial f(x;Δx)$.